# How to ignore a file input on a PHP form?

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I have a PHP form with an optional file input. If no file is chosen, and I do `print_r($_FILES)` after submission, I get this:

```
Array ( [the_file] => Array (
  [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) 
)
```

On forms with no file input, the $_FILES array is just empty, which is what I would prefer to happen if the optional file attachment input isn't used. After all, the "errors" here are really not errors - the user didn't intend to submit a file.

Is there a way to prevent a blank file input from being submitted, apart from reworking the form to use AJAX?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? If the user didn't choose a file, why not just ignore $_FILES entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error condition 4 corresponds to `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE`, which means [no file was uploaded](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php). Can't you just check for that, and if so, ignore the data in `$_FILES`?

Comment: Ah - I thought that meant 4 errors. :) I wonder why they don't put the actual error message there instead of a code?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a client script to remove the file input from the form on submit if it is unused.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple javascript on the main Uploading form , or use php check function for file sent by user!!